# Silverlight 5 Xml Serialization Error

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

I recently converted a project from Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5. In my project, I have many uses of the XmlSerializer class, where I either serialize or de-serialize my entity framework objects. I had no issues with this using silverlight 4, but for some reason when I to to create the XmlSerializer object in Silverlight 5 I get an error saying that it cannot reflect my object's type and that it "cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor." I had no problems with this in Siverlight 4, and it works if I take the "key" attribute out, but I cannot take the key attribute out because I am using ria services and it is required for what I am using it for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameterless constructor for the entity types that you are trying to serialize. i.e.

```
Public Sub New()

End Sub
```

You might need to place this in a Partial class in another file.